# Format a PayPal account to not take e-checks?

Tags: paypal

How do you configure a paypal account to NOT accept e-checks? Is this something that I adjust in my PP panel or can I send it in code when I make my "Buy Now" buttons?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a programming question to me...

Comment: Sounds like you might not be familiar with the PP API. It IS a programming question because these items can be set when a request is being sent from your page to PP

Comment: No, you're asking for something that can perhaps be adjusted without programming (the PP panel), and the sole answer as of the time of writing this is a non-programming solution.

Comment: So what? Sue me . . . geez guys, lighten up! "OMG not programming!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find the option in: Profile - Preferences - Selling Preferences.

The only stipulation is that Paypal won't let you refuse eCheques from eBay users.